# How to bind each arc of a pie chart with user-defined colors(for each arc)?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

```
       color=d3.scale.ordinal().domain(dataset.label)
       .range(temp);
```

dataset.label is the domain (arc label) for which user will give color requirement.temp is the array of values given by the user.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this code sample helps.

Assumes, `dataset.label` is an array of labels in dataset; where dataset is an array of objects and `temp` is an array of colour codes.

```
var  color=d3.scale.ordinal().domain(dataset.label)
       .range(temp);

var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
      .data(pie(dataset))
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "arc");

g.append("path")
      .attr("d", arc)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.label); });
```